# Android build differences eclipse versus ant

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

This topic may have been discussed in lengths but so far I haven't found the answer to my question, which is:

**Is there a structural, code or any other differences between the apks that eclipse plugin and ant produce?**

I have 2 environments running on the same JDK version and same Android SDK version - basically the latest ones.

The same code compiles successfully on both environments one of which is the dev environment using eclipse, the other one is the prod environment using ant.
Both environments sign the apk with the debug key.

**However, strangely enough, the performance of the ant generated apk is far slower than the performance of eclipse generated apk.**

I'd appreciate any help to figure out what could be missing in ant-generated apk build.
Any help greatly appreciated.

EDITED 14.02.2014 - in response to Stehpan. Code snippet added
Hi Stephan
The app encrypts about 20 string values of 15-40 characters each using AES and stores it in shared preferences. The ant generated app spends around 20 seconds to complete this while eclipse generated app completes very quickly.

Here is the method that does the encryption:

```
    public static final String encrypt(String value, char[] passPhrase){
    if(value != null){
        try{
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(SecureCrypto.generateSecretKey(passPhrase).getEncoded(), ENC_ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENC_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            value = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("utf-8")), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        }catch(Throwable th){
            Environment.logError(Environment.APPLICATION_LOG_TAG, th);
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Re-reading your question, I think I may have misunderstood it. Did you mean the performance of the apk is slower, or did you mean the performance of the packaging/compiling/building process is slower? The performance of what exactly? Does this happen the second time you launch each apk? or just the first time?

Comment: Hi Stephan, The performance of the app is slower. The initial startup of the ant built app takes like 20 seconds, while the eclipse-produced app starts like a breeze...

Comment: Again, does this happen a second time you launch each apk? Because there are a few things that are only done the first time an app is run on a device, not the second time.

Comment: The app sets up some encrypted paramaters upon each startup - 50-ish string values (15-40 character each) are being encrypted using AES and stored in the shared preferences. That snippet of code takes over 20 seconds in ant generated app.

Comment: Hi Stephan, I have edited my original question and added a code snippet too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a difference between Eclipse and using the command line. Essentially, Eclipse uses the same command line tools. The Eclipse user permission may end up getting a higher priority over the command lines. That's about it I'd think.

If there is any difference, it should be between your production apk and your debugging apk. In the production environment, some of your debugging code might get stripped out, minified, and possibly obfuscated.

Comment: Hi Stephan, The performance of the app is slower. The initial startup of the ant built app takes like 20 seconds, while the eclipse-produced app starts like a breeze...